# Ionic 3 split pane menu toggle not displayed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, splitpane

I'm  created my Ionic app for the [SplitPane](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/) , that one is working fine. 
but I faced some conflict 
**The split pane is displayed in large screens, but the toggle-menu button is not displayed in small screens.** and **When I swap it , then after the menu shows**.
Any one know how fix that issue in small devices 
look my code 
[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ceyr7a)

code part
**app.html**

```
<ion-split-pane>

  <ion-menu [content]="someContent">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Menu
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item (click)="setCategory('nature')">
          <ion-avatar item-left>

          </ion-avatar>
          <h3>Home</h3>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item (click)="setCategory('food')">
          <ion-avatar item-left>

          </ion-avatar>
          <h3>Categories</h3>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item (click)="setCategory('people')">
          <ion-avatar item-left>

          </ion-avatar>
          <h3>Get One</h3>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item (click)="setCategory('people')">
          <ion-avatar item-left>

          </ion-avatar>
          <h3>Settings</h3>
        </ion-item>


        <ion-item (click)="setCategory('people')">
          <ion-avatar item-left>

          </ion-avatar>
          <h3>My Partner</h3>
        </ion-item>


      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #someContent main></ion-nav>

</ion-split-pane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the menu toggle button in your page header like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <!-- Add this button in the pages you want to show the menu button -->
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

This way when the pane is shown it'll not show the menu button, but when in smaller screens and the pane is hidden, the button is shown.